# React components not rendered on url change with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

My application is not rendering the matching components for the given route. When the application loads at url `/` and I click the login button, the url changes from `/` to `/login`. However, the `Login` component does not render. With the url currently at `/login`, the `Login` component will only render when refreshed.

I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"`. Please let me know of any possible solutions. Thank you.

```
// App.js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'  
    
<Router>
  <NavBar />
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>

// NavBar
<>
  <Typography>
    <Button component={Link} to='/'>
      Home
    </Button>
  </Typography>
  <Button component={Link} to='/login'>
    Login
  </Button>
  <Button component={Link} to='/signup'>
    Signup
  </Button>
</>

// Login
<Router>
  <Link to='/signup'>Sign up here</Link>
</Router>

// Signup
<Router>
  <Link to='/login'>here</Link>
</Router>
```

My attempts at solving the issue:

- Have the `BrowswerRouter as Router` wrap App in `index.js`
- Use `withRoute` like this `component={withRouter(Login)}`
- Check the order of routes
- `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router'` instead of `'react-router-dom'`
- wrap the url link like this <Button color='inherit' component={Link} `to={'/'}` />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use useHistory hook

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

  const history = useHistory();
```

Then add this to ur button

```
onClick={() => history.push("/login")};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't wrap the content of signup and login components with `Router`.